# Fastest way to cat from multiple files to multiple files

Tags: bash, performance, cat

Using bash (and any standard tools), what is the quickest way to cat a large amount of files?

- I have multiple folders containing multiple files of genetic data.
- Each folder name is the species name.
- Each filename starts with the query name, followed by species name.
- Each file contains two lines, first line is the sequence ID, and the second line is genetic data.

I.e. folder name:

> speciesName

E.g. folder names:

> SolanumCommersonii

> SolanumLycopersicum

I.e. file name:

> queryName_speciesName

E.g. file names:

> Q12P34_SolanumCommersonnii.fasta

> Q56P78_SolanumCommersonnii.fasta

> Q12P34_SolanumLycopersicum.fasta

Example file contents:

> >sequenceID blah blah blah
>
> acgtagctagctagtcgatgctagcggctatatgcgatctagtca

There are about 45,000 files per species and about 10 species.

I want to iterate through each file and cat it to a file that is for that specific query name so that all the different species sequence IDs and genetic data is in a file for that specific query.

I've managed to write a bash script to do so, but it feels like I could make this process faster. Currently it's taking a couple of hours to complete using the following:

```
readarray -t folders < speciesList.txt
mkdir -p joined
for folder in ${folders[@]}
do
    foldCont=($(ls "$folder"))
    for fileN in ${foldCont[@]}
    do
        cat "$folder"/"$fileN" >> joined/"${fileN%_"${folder}"*}"_allCords.fna 
    done
    echo "finished with ""$folder"
done
```

E.g speciesList.txt:

> SolanumCommersonnii
>
> SolanumLycopersicum

Any help to make this faster would be appreciated. I've thought about maybe using xargs, but not sure if that would be any quicker.

EDIT:
E.g. file contents (filename shown here also):

Q12P34_SolanumCommersonnii.fasta

> > Q12P34_Solanum_commersonii cultivar 41
>
> tcaacgtagctagctagtcgatgctagcgaggctatatgcgatctagtca

Q56P78_SolanumCommersonnii.fasta

> > Q56P78_Solanum_commersonii cultivar 49
>
> tcgatgctagcgaggctatatgcgatctagtcagactaaata

Q12P34_SolanumLycopersicum.fasta

> > Q12P34_SolanumLycopersicum cultivar 98
>
> tgctagcgaggctatatgcgatctagtcgaagaagaattataaa

E.g. expected output files:

joined/Q12P34_allCords.fna

> > Q12P34_Solanum_commersonii cultivar 41
>
> tcaacgtagctagctagtcgatgctagcgaggctatatgcgatctagtca
>
> > Q12P34_SolanumLycopersicum cultivar 98
>
> tgctagcgaggctatatgcgatctagtcgaagaagaattataaa

joined/Q56P78_allCords.fna

> > Q56P78_Solanum_commersonii cultivar 49
>
> tcgatgctagcgaggctatatgcgatctagtcagactaaata

Comment: Don't use `bash` if speed is important.

Comment: how many distinct `query` names/strings?  45K?

Comment: consider updating the question to include the contents of your 3x sample files along with the expected results (corresponding to those 3x sample files); do the entries in the consolidated files need to be created in any particular order (eg, sorted by species)?

Comment: for a given `query` name/string, will there be a matching file for *all* 10 species? or could the number of species, per `query`, vary?

Comment: You don't need a loop; `cat "$folder"/* > joined/...` should work fine. Your main bottleneck here is simply I/O, which you can't really do anything about short of buying faster disks. (If you have command-length issues, `find "$folder" -exec cat {} + > joined/...` will work as well.)

Comment: There are sometimes faster approaches if you're on a specialty filesystem with reflink support (as available on btrfs, or xfs when formatted with experimental features turned on) and your output files can afford to have data aligned to page boundaries; but you wouldn't be using `cat` at all in that case.

Comment: btw, `array=( $(anything) )` is an antipattern; see [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29) for details. In this particular case, `foldCont=( "$folder"/* )` is the simpler alternative (if you need to strip the directory names, follow with `foldCont=( "${foldCont[@]##*/}" )` to reduce to basenames).

Comment: BTW, `echo "finished with ""$folder"` is **exactly** the same as `echo "finished with $folder"`; the doubled-up quotes cancel each other out.

Comment: But, bottom line -- xargs or `find ... -exec ... {} +` could help if you were spending a significant amount of time starting up new copies of `cat` (as could be the case if you were merging tons of tiny files), but if your time is being spent _actually writing your output data_ (as would be the case with relatively large files), then it won't make an appreciable difference.

Comment: Cutting over to the page alignment question: Can a fasta file have a block of NULs (or newlines, or any other filler character) in it without changing the meaning of the content? (Again, you won't be able to apply the possible answer this suggests unless you're using a very modern filesystem).

Comment: You might test how long `time { for ((i=0; i<45000; i++)); do cat /dev/null; done; }` takes to run; that's roughly the amount of time that xargs could save you, if I'm understanding things correctly; adjust the number appropriately otherwise. If it's an appreciable part of your runtime, great! Otherwise, you'll need to look to other approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback all. Will go through and answer your questions now.

Comment: @Barmar - Okie. What do you suggest?

Comment: @markp-fuso - Yes, 45k distinct query names. Will update question with more samples. And no, not a matching file for all 10 species. Some only have 5k, some 20k, some 45k.

Comment: Just about anything else, such as Python or C.

Comment: @chepner - How would that work in with parameter expansion and the variable of the filename?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Thanks for all the tips, comments and suggestions. I think there is quite a bit of time being spent on starting new copies of `cat` as they are all small files, about 500 to 2k bytes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Fasta files can have newlines, however i've formatted mine to be one line (well, two. The seq ID, then the nucleotides all on the second line as one big string)

Comment: Okay, if the files are that small, it's certainly not worth trying to use reflinks; they'd need to be a _minimum_ of 8kb to get any advantage, and probably quite a lot larger than that (personally, I'd only put dev time into a reflink-based approach if the files were in the megabytes).

Comment: See if the `find ... -exec cat {} +` approach suggested by chepner buys you anything.

Comment: (btw, I'd personally reach for Golang here, or Julia if you know it; either is less error-prone than C while being faster than Python... but again, that's personal taste and familiarity speaking; if a program is I/O-bound, Python is typically quite fast enough).

Comment: This has to be asked before the fastest solution can be found:  what exactly is your file system configuration? Including hard drive(s) and storage controller(s).  If you're reading and writing from the same *S-L-O-W* 5400 RPM 8TB drive, all the gyrations of finding the fastest way to copy the files are like feeding PEDs to a gerbil trying to haul a freight train.  Uphill.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I was going to try out the `find ... -exec cat {} +`, but the time test for 45,000 `cat`s took 1m54s. So, looks like it's mostly IO. Also, having issues trying to figure out how to correctly use parameter expansion with `{}` of the `find` `-exec` command. But yeah, I'll leave it there I think as it won't gain me appreciable time. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AndrewHenle - It's on a SAN. I think it's a RAID 6 using 24x 4TB disks. However, I've found out there is a 1TB RAM disk available for use, so will try that and see if that helps.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Maybe for completeness sake I should figure out how to get it working using `find ... -exec cat {} +` ... My main problem for this is trying to get it to output to the correct file

Comment: *I think it's a RAID 6 using 24x 4TB disks.*  Ouch.  That is extremely likely to be ***PAINFULLY*** slow.  I guess your SAN admins never heard of [read-modify-write](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/usenix2000/freenix/full_papers/gopinath/gopinath_html/node24.html)?  Something like a 24-disk RAID6 array is literally decades-old in the "don't do ***THAT***" book of RAID configuration.  An array like that under random small-block writes like you're doing can be reduced to a handful of KB/sec of IO throughput.

Comment: Re: parameter expansion, `-exec bash -c 'for arg in "$@"; do ...; done' _ {} +` lets you do parameter expansion on `$arg` (or for that matter `"$@"`). Mind, there's a lot of care needed to not lose the performance advantages one gets from `-exec ... {} +` in that case.

Comment: (and keeping the `{}` out of the `bash -c '...'` string is utterly critical for security, or else your file names can inject code).

Comment: ...however, the idea of what chepner gave you was to run one copy of `find` per output file, so you don't have the output file being determined within the `-exec`; instead, you have each copy of `find` finding and concatenating only inputs that go to a single output, opened before the `find` executable even starts operation.

Comment: If you don't want to go that route, but want to have exactly one copy of `find` iterating over all your inputs, I'd think of using awk, which has automated caching of file descriptors: unlike bash, in awk you can use `>$file` over and over referring to the same file (or different ones) without doing an actual `open()` syscall each time. Also, unlike bash, awk's file I/O is able to take advantage of buffering. (I could go into _why_ POSIX-y shells do file I/O the way they do, but it's arguably neither here nor there).

Comment: @AndrewHenle - I was a erroneous with my comment re the SAN. It is RAID 5 in a 4+1 config. I think it's 24 disks per unit (so like, 20 hot disks with 4 available for hotswaps between the 4 raid groups?) and about 4 or so units connected with fibre switching. It's a pretty sweet setup, but I'm fuzzy on exact details.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Thanks for that. I'll give it a try this afternoon (both the -exec way and the `awk` way. And again, thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - Forgot to mention, loved your gerbil analogy!